# Look-up Columns redirecting to folders changed their behaviour

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, lookup-column, folder

I am using SharePoint Online site.

Some months ago I created a lookup column in document library [A] that referred to another document library [B]. This was the best option I found to be able to refer attachments to each documents in [A], using in [B] a field that is filled only for folders and not for documents.

It was working fine, when clicking on the look-up field, it used to give the possibility of checking the documents directly in a pop-up window or to open the folder in another view.

Since a couple of months this doesn't work anymore, now when clicking on the look-up field, it opens the "Properties of the folder" (that means just the name of it) and doesn't show the content of the folder itself.

What's changed? How can I solve this?

Comment: By default lookups open Display forms of the connected items or folders.

Comment: @harshalgite Ok, so that means that the Display form was changed? It was working differently when I set it up, and I'm quite sure we didn't change anything. I should probably check through Sharepoint Designer, because from infopath it doesn't let me (unfortunately I'm not the administrator)

Comment: Right now if you click on your lookup and you will see your folder name (along with that folders other properties). Click on that folder name, it will open the folder location. But that increases 1 more click in your requirement.

Comment: It would increase one click but it would still be useful. The problem is that it doesn't work like that, if I click on the name of the folder, it lets me modifiy it instead, unfortunately. There is no way to get to the folder. I can only go back to the previous folder, and then search for the correct attachment.

Comment: One more info: if I go to the properties of the document in library [A] and click on the text in the lookup fields, it works perfectly, as it used to. Any idea would be very helpful.

Comment: I "solved it" (hoping to find soon something better) formatting the column as follows: {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "txtContent": "@currentField.lookupValue",
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "='http address of the attachment folder' + @currentField.lookupValue"
  }
}